# Spring MVC with a rich client framework

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller, primefaces, richfaces

I have several applications that are structured as follows

```
DataComponent

WebComponent
ThickClientComponent
WebServices
```

The DataComponent has all the functionality required to access the application's data so it contains the DAOs and the JPA entities. The other three modules are:

- WebComponent - A spring MVC application that uses the DataComponent for data acccess
- ThickClientComponent- A Swing application that uses the DataComponent for data access
- WebServices - A SOAP based services that also uses the DataComponent.

All three projets have the DataComponent as a dependeny in their Maven POM file.

I would like to use a rich client framework like RichFaces, icefaces or primefaces as i need to be able to use the rich components are available in rich client frameworks (i.e. trees, panel, drag and drop etc).

I have looked around and i cant seem to find an example where a Spring MVC application uses a rich client platform. Is it possible? Are the rich client platforms a framework meaning that i have to use either Spring MVC or the rich client platform but not both?

The DataComponent module is spring based.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to go for [GWT](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/). It is a very good rich client framework and it has a very huge set of components available including drag-and-drop. Also it provides the integration with Spring Framework. You can check out [this](http://technophiliac.wordpress.com/2008/08/24/giving-gwt-a-spring-in-its-step/) and [this](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?74460-Spring4gwt-fresh-approach-at-Spring-GWT-integration) links to know more about its integration.

I have also used **smartGWT** that is extension of GWT components in one of my project that has backend in Spring framework.

Hope this helps you. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this module will sort you out:

http://static.springsource.org/spring-webflow/docs/2.0-m1/reference/spring-faces.html

Comment: It uses Spring Webflow. Does it work with Spring MVC? Spring webflow is probably overkill for what i want to do.

Comment: Why dismiss it before you're tried it?  Spring web flow is a complement to Spring MVC.

Comment: Spring Web flow will require some changes to the Controllers which i would like to avoid. I was really looking to replace the "View" part of the Web application. I will investigate web flow a bit more to see if i can use it.

Comment: I really do not recommend spring web flow, I use it in a big project and taking appart the huge amount of bugs we found, it was really confusing for the developers to use it, at the end the code waesnt clear or easy to maintain.

Comment: And RichFaces is an improvement?  I don't think so.

Answer (score 1):

You can try ext-js for creating your client side interface.  It's heavily java script / ajax based, but that would probably meet your needs.  It doesn't really care what your backed tech is, since it works entire through javascript and ajax.

Answer (score 1):

Yess you can use Spring MVC with PrimeFaces but you have to use it with the spring JSF 2 implementation.

If you are thinking to use some faces framework definitely use PrimeFaces.

You could use SpringMVC with JSF but I also recommend to you not to use SpringMVC JSF implementation. Use insted the MyFaces JSF 2 implementation with Primefaces and then link the backing beans with spring.

From my experience this is the best.

But I guess any other options are fine too.

Comment: Are you able to suggest some examples of how this was achieved?

Comment: Maybe this couple of tutorials will help you http://www.roseindia.net/jsf/myfacesspring/ 
http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/jsf-2-0-spring-hibernate-integration-example/

At the end just configure a JSF 2 project using my faces and configure the business and DAO layer with spring. Then to inject the Spring beans to your backing beans you can do @ManageProperty(#"spring bean name"). Also give it a try to MAVEN.